# A Turing machine x The Turing machine, articles in scientific concepts and tools

Tags: grammar, articles, genitive-construction

I would like to understand why sometimes the indefinite article is used, I thought that the whole name, the concept is "the Turing machine". In texts, I often see it used as a regular noun (the first mention is with "a", then with "the"].
We do not say "a Newton Theory of Gravity",as far as I know. What is the difference then?

> We may think of a Turing machine as a...

but

> We used Fourier analysis to evaluate the

Why here "analysis" does not need an article?

Can it be because we regarding the machine, can talk about a specific instance? But even then I would say we still talk about the concept, which is still the same.

Comment: Great question! However, your title doesn’t seem to match your question. Could you edit it so that it matches?

Comment: @Fivesideddice Thanks, done. I also clarified in the text so that it matches better.

Answer (score 1):

The word "analysis" can be either a countable or an uncountable noun. When used in an uncountable sense, it doesn't require an article.

"Machine" is a countable noun. It's true that "Turing machine" is an abstract concept and a mathematical model of computation. Grammatically, however, "machine" sounds strange without an article. To make it uncountable, we'd have to say "Turing machinery" but no one says that.